# How do you list the last 10 accessed files in your directory in unix?

Tags: unix

So I want to run a command on shell that can return the last 10 accessed files in unix the whole directory is huge so i would only like to see last 10 ...

Answer (score 5):

```
ls -ltur | tail -10
```

Tough, this will still take a lot of time, since the filtering is done after reading the whole directory. But at least, you save the displaying of non-interesting entries (which can be slow on some terminal emulators).

Comment: OK. You win with the `-u`, but you can skip the `-r` and use `head` as well and that may be faster.

Comment: `ls -ltur | tail` will be enough. Save keystrokes by omitting the ` -10` which is the default anyway. Same default applies to head by the way.